# Phing UpToDateTask with mapper?

Tags: php, build-process, sass, phing

Can someone give me an example of how to use Phing's `UpToDateTask` with a
mapper? I can't figure it out and I can't find any examples on the net.

Here's what I am trying to achieve. I have a bunch of SCSS files that I
convert to CSS using the `ExecTask` and Ruby's SASS parser. But, I only
want to regenerate the CSS files if any of the source files have changed.

The source SCSS files are in `app/assets/css` and the compiled files are
placed in `app/webroot/css`. How can I use the `UpToDateTask` to test if any
of the files in `app/assets/css` are newer than any of the files in
`app/webroot/css`?

Note that the SASS comilation does not have a 1-to-1 filename mapping to
CSS files. There could be a dozen SCSS files that in the end get
compiled into 3-4 CSS files. I know I could simply hard-code those CSS files into my `build.xml` but I would like to create a more generic, re-usable build target.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for myself using trial and error. The scenario I described above (testing if any file in a source directory is newer than any file in a destination directory) cannot be achieved using a mapper in the `uptodate` task. The `uptodate` task simply iterates over the `fileset`, converts any filename using the `mapper` and then compares that file with the original file.

For the time being I am using a fileset that includes all files that do not start with an underscore (which are SASS includes) and a simple mapper that just globs `*.scss` to `*.css`. It works, but it's not perfect. When only one of the include files changes (those starting with an underscore) then Phing will not detect any changes and skip rebuilding the CSS assets.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance which result files will exist, you can use an identity mapper to check if each of the source files are newer than a single result file. Do that for each result file, and you'll know if there have been changes.

Comment: I know. I was trying to find a more generic way, so that I don't have to modify my build script just because I added a new SCSS file.